# Formal Methods - Algebraic Specification vs Object Oriented

Tags: formal-methods

I am in the middle of some research and have not been able to find much literature to help, I want to compare the platform dependencies of the two formal methods; algebraic specification and object oriented. Which language would they use?

Does anyone have any knowledge of this or could point me to the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what "algebraic specification" means (GIYF: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_specification) as my company has built such a system and used it industrial practice.  The "language" is that of abstract data types, function signatures and axioms describing what the functions do, with  ADTs, signatures, and axioms often packaged into parameterized "algebras" which can be combined to form more complex algebras.

I'm not sure what you mean by "object oriented" (specification).  Most OO "designs" are simply sets of classes (which implicitly represent the data types) and signatures, with no attached semantics.    I'd hardly call those a "specification"; rather, they are are "sketch".

Comment: Thank you for your answer....So in terms of platform dependency would it be correct to say algebraic uses specific languages like CASL and can be platform dependant according to its complexity and chosen language where as object oriented is pretty basic as it can be simple as using UML diagrams on any windows, mac or linux computer?

Comment: If by CASL you mean this kind of thing: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1139752  then I guess the answer is yes.  The question about platform dependency completely throws me for a loop; most algebraic specification systems run on some platform [but that isn't of real interest], but what they specify almost never has platform dependencies in it; they mostly don't have the vocabulary.  The same is true of UML based tools.  (Although some UML diagrams related to deployment can name a platform in what I consider by a pretty ad hoc way).

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, but specifications, by definition, are platform independent. If you are looking for a specification language that supports object oriented modelling, I suppose VDM++ is a good fit.

Comment: Platform independent?  Really abstract specifications might be.  As a practical matter, specifications simply have less details than the implementations they implicitly describe.  They can be *very* platform specific and still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this paper may help you. It is available online (google it), However, I'm not sure if it is published or not. Nothing about it in the authors DBLP.

"Comparison of Object-Oriented Formal Methods", by Nicolas Guel, Olivier Biberstein, Didier Buchs, Ercument Canver, Marie-Claude Gaudel, Friedrich von Henke, Detlef Schwier.